# Adding Simple Foreign Key Constraint to my Table

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure what mistake I'm making, please help.

```
ALTER TABLE tyresys_tyre_model 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_manufacturer_tyre_model 
FOREIGN KEY (ManufacturerId) 
REFERENCES tyresys_manufacturer(Id)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

DATABASE ERROR

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`#sql-2494_108`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_manufacturer_tyre_model` FOREIGN KEY (`ManufacturerId`) REFERENCES
>   `tyresys_manufacturer` (`Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Table - tyresys_manufacturer

```
Id - int

Name
```

Table
tyresys_tyre_model

```
Id

ManufacturerId - int

Name
```

is there an easy way to do this? instead of doing an SQL query?

Comment: are those tables populated already ?

Comment: This might be happening because of data already present in the table. Can you verify it once.

Comment: thank you guys for your help, there was a data in the tyre_model table that have wrong key. which causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably  `tyresys_tyre_model` table contains `ManufacturerId` value that that is not in your `tyresys_manufacturer` table. You'll have to `delete/update` those records first.

You execute the following query to get those `ManufacturerId`s

```
SELECT ManufacturerId FROM tyresys_tyre_model  WHERE tyresys_tyre_model  NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM tyresys_manufacturer)
```

Comment: There was a data in tyre_model table and when i deleted it, it works.
thank you so much, i was stuck in this problem for hours last night, so stressed. just a simple mistake ruined all those research.